# Map a range of values to a single value

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to map values ranging between `lowerBound` and `upperBound` to a certain value.

**Illustrative Example:**

For example, imagine I have GPS system which has users subscribed to it. This system is able to provide me the distance of the user from a certain point. Based on the distance of the user I want to assign them an ID.

Thus users in distance from

- `1` to `100` get `ID: 8.4`
- `101` to `200` get `ID: 7.2`
- `201` to `300` get `ID: 3.6`
- `401` to `600` get `ID: 4.1`

and so on...

**My approach:**

So what I did, I created an `std::map` by initializing it as follows:

```
   std::map<int, double> distanceToIdMap; 

   distanceToIdMap =
    {
            {100, 8.4},
            {200, 7.2},
            {300, 3.6},
    };
```

Then I use this code to get the ID for the given distance:

```
double roundUpToHundred = std::ceil(realDistance / 100.0) * 100;
double powerForDistance = distanceToIdMap.at(roundUpToHundred);
```

However my approach breaks down for the `401` to `600` distance, because by ceiling to the nearest hundred for a distance of `400+` I get the value `500` for which I don't have an entry in the map. Of course the trivial solution would be to add an entry for `500` to the `distanceToIdMap` but that is not how I want to handle this problem.

I would like to have a map with `{(lowerbound, upperbound) , correspondingID}` structure so I can address cases where an ID covers distance spanning more than 100m. And a given can check if the `lowerBound` < `realDistance` < `upperBound` and then provide the ID.

Comment: Do you want holes in your mapping? If not then it's not necessary to provide both a beginning and ending to each range, the ending should be equal to the beginning of the next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a use case for [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/). Note that `lower_bound` is the correct implementation, not `upper_bound`. This code compiles and works. The `map` does not need to be sorted, as it is already sorted. This should run in *O(log(N))*.

You'll need to catch the exception...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

std::map<int, double> distanceToIdMap =
    {
            {100, 8.4},
            {200, 7.2},
            {300, 3.6},
            {600, 4.1}
    };   

double Distance(int user)
{
    auto x = std::lower_bound(distanceToIdMap.begin(), distanceToIdMap.end(), std::pair<const int,double>(user,0));
    if (x == distanceToIdMap.end()) throw std::runtime_error("can't find");
    return x->second;
}

int main()
{
    for(int user=25;user < 650;user+=25)
    {
        cout << user << " " << Distance(user) << std::endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sh-4.3# g++ -o main *.cpp -std=c++11                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
sh-4.3# main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
25 8.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
50 8.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
75 8.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
100 8.4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
125 7.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
150 7.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
175 7.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
200 7.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
225 3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
250 3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
275 3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
300 3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
325 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
350 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
375 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
400 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
425 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
450 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
475 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
500 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
525 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
550 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
575 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
600 4.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'                                                                                                                                                                                     
  what():  can't find                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Aborted (core dumped)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
sh-4.3# main
```

Comment: just couple of questions for clarification before I accept an answer: **1)** how does this approach differ from the `map::upper_bound` given in @pascx64 answer? **2)** (just out of curiosity) is there a specific reason for naming `double Distance(int user)` function with the upper-case `Distance`? **3)** what is the role of the `std::pair<const int,double>(user,0)`

Comment: 1) this is equivalent to the ones using `map::lower_bound`; I wasn't aware that map supported `lower_bound` directly, so I used the general function to perform the same thing. The other answer are simpler 2) My naming convention uses capitals for all functions or methods. 3) the pair is the comparison object. A `map` object is an iterable list of `pairs`, and it is sorted by the `first` (key) of the pair.

Comment: `map::lower_bound` exists because `std::lower_bound` is inefficient when applied to a `map` - it doesn't have random access iterators. *Always* use the member function when it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try `upper_bound` :

```
 auto upper  = distanceToIdMap.upper_bound( 50 );
 std::cout << "value:" << upper->second << std::endl;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/upper_bound/

Comment: for the map I have in the question, what happens if I do `distanceToIdMap.upper_bound( 312 );`

Comment: It will take the `401 to 600` range because you didn't put any value between 300 and 401 ( I'm not sure if it's a mistake in your question ? )

Answer (score 2):

with `std::map::lower_bound` and `boost::optional`, you may do something like:

```
const std::map<int, boost::optional<double>> distanceToIdMap =
{
    {0, boost::none},
    {100, 8.4},
    {200, 7.2},
    {300, 3.6},
    {400, boost::none},
    {600, 4.1}
};

for (auto v : {-10, 50, 99, 100, 101, 250, 350, 500, 601})
{
    auto it = distanceToIdMap.lower_bound(v);

    if (it != distanceToIdMap.end() && it->second) {
        std::cout << v << " " << *it->second << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << v << " None" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/RHUS4I)

Answer (score 1):

What about avoiding maps at all?

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> table =
{
    {0, 0},
    {94.5, 2.1},
    {314.4, 4.7}
} ;

double distance = ...
double value = std::upper_bound(table.begin(), table.end(), std::pair(distance, 0)) ;
```

Drawback: table must be properly ordered.

Comment: I think you forgot the template in your `std::pair(distance, 0)`, should be `std::pair<double,double>( distance, 0.0 )`

Comment: yes, or I could have used std::make_pair(distance, 0.0) ;

Comment: And `upper_bound` return iterator not `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
int mapdistance[] = {100,200,300};
double mapid[] = {8.4,7.2,3.6};
double dist=0;
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(mapdistance)/sizeof(int);i++) {
   dist += mapdistance[i];
   if (realdistance<=dist) return mapid[i];
}
```

Comment: If you keep things sorted, you can use a binary search on your bounds check as well, if your mapdistance array starts getting big.  Of course, this is a very C solution to a C++ stated problem :)

Comment: What do you mean? It compiles in C++ :) The question as asked already had the values sorted, so I assumed they would continue that way.  My system is linearly searched (N) and would not work with a binary since I'm adding the value to dist for each mapdistance.